# D3.js incluir imagem externa no terceiro botão

Tags: javascript, imagem, url, d3.js

este é um trecho de um index.html do D3.js que tenho feito, minha ideia é incluir uma imagem externa e fazer com que apareça clicando no botão 'btn3'. No botão 1 e 2 tenho dois gráficos que funcionam normalmente, o problema é fazer com que o botão 3 exiba a imagem (de um link), o D3.json é um exemplo que estou tentando utilizar para teste. Outras opções são bem vindas. Agradeço as ajudas.

```
<button id="btn1">Sobreviventes e mortos por grupos</button>
<button id="btn2">Sobreviventes e mortos por porta de embarque</button>
<button id="btn3">Fotos</button>


<div id="chartContainer">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // novo gráfio bubble incluso 

        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
        d3.csv("d3_1.csv", function (data) {
            var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
            myChart.setBounds(65, 30, 505, 330)
            myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Embarked", "Survived"]);
            myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Amount");
            myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Amount");
            myChart.addSeries("Survived", dimple.plot.bubble);   
            myChart.addLegend(70, 10, 510, 20, "right");
            myChart.draw();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        d3.select("#btn1").on("click", function(){
            d3.select("svg").remove();     
            var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
            d3.csv("d3_1.csv", function (data) {
                var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                myChart.setBounds(65, 30, 505, 330)
                myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Embarked", "Survived"]);
                myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Amount");
                myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Amount");
                myChart.addSeries("Survived", dimple.plot.bubble);
                myChart.addLegend(70, 10, 510, 20, "right");
                myChart.draw();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        d3.select("#btn2").on("click", function(){
            d3.select("svg").remove();
            var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400);
            d3.csv("d3_1.csv", function (data) {
                var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                myChart.setBounds(80, 30, 480, 330)
                myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Amount");
                myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", ["Embarked", "Survived"]);
                myChart.addSeries("Survived", dimple.plot.bar);
                myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 510, 20, "right");
                myChart.draw();

            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>

        d3.select("#btn3").on("click", function(){
            // Fazer com que o link abaixo funcione com o botão acima exibindo a imagem

            d3.json("http://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn.json?limit=80", function(error, imgs) {
                // filter out posts without a thumbnail
                var images = imgs.data.children.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.data.thumbnail.slice(-3) == "jpg";
                });

                images.forEach(function(img) {
                    d3.select("body")
                      .append("a")
                      .attr("href", img.data.url)
                      .append("img")
                      .attr({
                        height: 66,
                        src: img.data.thumbnail
             });        
        });
    </script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa especificar os atributos da imagem separadamente, e não em lote. Observando que havia uma função sem fechar:

```
d3.select("#btn3").on("click", function(){
    // Fazer com que o link abaixo funcione com o botão acima exibindo a imagem

    d3.json("http://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn.json?limit=80", function(error, imgs) {
        // filter out posts without a thumbnail
        var images = imgs.data.children.filter(function(d) {
            return d.data.thumbnail.slice(-3) == "jpg";
        });

        images.forEach(function(img) {
            d3.select("body")
            .append("a")
            .attr("href", img.data.url)
            .append("img")
            .attr("src",img.data.thumbnail)
            .attr("height","66")
        });
    }); // estava faltando esse fechamento       
});
```

Comment: a solução acima ajudou, porém algo estranho acontece, o terceiro botão aciona o link das imagens mas aparece totalmente fora do contexto, aparece no rodapé da página. Porém, o gráfico do botão 1 e 2 não foram projudicados. Uma coisa que não comentei é que o trecho do <style> body que pertence ao código do 'btn3' eu incluí lá no início, mas não creio que seja isso que atrapalhou, porém ainda sou um aprendiz de D3 e fico no aguardo de mais algumas dicas. Acho que ajuda eu colocar o link original do código que estou testando no btn3, http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/76739ae4271e8c111d2e

Comment: @JRafael Aí teria que ver todo o seu HTML pra descobrir o problema.

Comment: então, fui pesquisar um modo de poder compartilhar aqui e consegui através deste link: http://plnkr.co/edit/cDSi82j8kMLSTKxEQJG9?p=preview, uma obs. é que o terceiro botão 'Fotos' seria uma foto só (que eu quero inserir - outra coisa que preciso ver como faz), estou usando exatamente o código deste script aqui: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/76739ae4271e8c111d2e, foi o único no bl.ocks.org que chega mais próximo da ideia que tive, mas estou aberto há outras opções caso essa não tenha jeito de implementar no meu código. Att.